# Formatting dates for use in mysql BETWEEN statement?

Tags: java

If I want to format a String that contains a date in such a way that I can use it in the `BETWEEN` section of my mysql query how would I go about doing this?

```
String str = "Tue Sep 17 01:48:10 EDT 2013" // this string is passed into my function in this format.

String select = "SELECT id, consumption, date_time FROM consumption_info WHERE date_time BETWEEN '2013-09-15 00:00:00' AND '2013-09-17 00:00:00' GROUP BY id";
```

the problem is I can't use str the way it is - it's not formatted the right way. I thought I could use:

```
Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(str );
```

`String finalDate = temp.toString()` - but even this does not return what I want...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try this kind of date time format '2013-03-14 07:35:35.000'. I am using this in my queries and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `PreparedStatement` instead, e.g.:

```java
    Date d1 = ...;
    Date d2 = ...;
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT id, consumption, date_time " 
        + "FROM consumption_info WHERE date_time BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY id");
    ps.setDate(1, d1);
    ps.setDate(2, d2);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

*Note, that in this case, `d1` and `d2` are of type `java.sql.Date`.*

Answer (score 2):

You have to first parse the date from

```
String str = "Tue Sep 17 01:48:10 EDT 2013"
```

Like

```
Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(str );
```

And then use this date object

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
sdf.format(new Date(temp));
```

This will produce the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

`temp.toString()` is Date objects default `toString()` method, it is not going to print in the format you are expecting.

In your case SimpleDateFormat has to be used twice. Once to convert the Date in String to be converted to java.util.Date object. Then the Date has to be converted bact to String in the format expected in SQL. You can achieve as below,

```
String str = "Tue Sep 17 01:48:10 EDT 2013";

SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

// String to date
Date tempDate = sdf1.parse(str);
// Date to required format in String
String tempStr = sdf2.format(tempDate);

System.out.println(tempStr);
```

*Note: Explicitly specify the `SimpleDateFormat` `locale` to `English` in first parse, otherwise it will use the platform `default` locale which may not be English.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify timezone when parsing/formatting date string. Take a look at this code.

```
String str = "Tue Sep 17 01:48:10 IST 2013" ;
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"); // for example, use your own
sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
Date date = sdf.parse(str);
SimpleDateFormat sdf1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00");
sdf1.setTimeZone(tz);
String dateStr = sdf1.format(date);
String qryStr = "SELECT id, consumption, date_time FROM consumption_info 
     WHERE date_time BETWEEN '2013-09-15 00:00:00' AND '"+dateStr+"' GROUP BY id";
```